# uploading a repository to github fails says "permission denied"

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and when I try to upload my newly created repository to github I get the message:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

: Any idea what this means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you forget to add your public key to the github project settings? Also check to make sure your private key is in your .ssh directory.

Goto https://github.com/[username here]/[project name here]/edit and make sure your public key is set.

Read this too: http://help.github.com/mac-key-setup/

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem but i solved using the following steps

> 1. First of all i add  ssh key to my github account which is not added before.        use following command in git bash $ssh-keygen -t rsa -C
>      "your_email@youremail.com"
>
>    it generates the new file new_key.pub file whatever you put the file
>      name during the key generation process.
> 2. paste your new_key.pub into GitHub.    go to GitHub Account -> setting -> ssh key -> add ssh key
> 3. now rename the new_key.pub into id_rsa.pub.

and it solved my problem