# Github push error. Permission denied

Tags: git, github

I am just trying to create my first repo from Ubuntu 11.10 with this command:

I was about to finish `sudo git push -u origin master`

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

How can this be fixed?

I tried this too. i.e git push -u origin master. I got this error.

> error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied
>   error: could not lock config file .git/config: 
>   Permission denied
>   Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
>   error: unable to create directory for .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
>   error: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'.
>   Everything up-to-date

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2503724/1061748) be of any help?

Quote:

> Did you forget to add your public key to the github project settings?
>   Also check to make sure your private key is in your .ssh directory.
>
> Goto https://github.com/[username here]/[project name here]/edit and
>   make sure your public key is set.
>
> Read this too: http://help.github.com/mac-key-setup/

Comment: Yep, it might the true reason. :)

Answer (score 6):

If you're just creating a repo,  there's no need to do a git push; git init will create the repo. Also, I would stay away from using sudo when running git. You might also want to go to this site to help you understand git: http://progit.org/book/ch1-3.html

If you are using github, you might want to read this: http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/

Answer (score 2):

Hello it could be because you're trying to git push as root, with sudo, did you set your public key or root key, usually you just supply your key and not the root key, that could be why you're getting such error.

Answer (score 1):

If you think it's because of false lock, try removing the lock file:

**Mac or *nix**

```
rm -v .git/config.lock
```

**Windows**

```
del .git/config.lock
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to hazard a guess that you might be using something like etckeeper to keep version control history of /etc changes - which seems to require you to use sudo (at least it makes sense that it would).

I had the same issue as you - I needed to use sudo but could not get it working with the keys registered at github (which was noted as the same key that I was using as my regular sudo user)

What you need is the -E flag - there was no other changes required (assuming you set up for ssh vs https

```
➜ sudo -E git push -u origin master
Enumerating objects: 8, done.
Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 661 bytes | 661.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (4/4), completed with 2 local objects.
To github.com:[redacted].git
   5fedc61..3a9b7f6  master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
(base)
```